# Entity Framework Is Null, Is Not Null Using DB2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, db2

I tried this:

```
<pre>var query = this.context.PERFIL_ALERTA.Where(x => x.CodigoEmpresa == EmpresaId && x.IdAtividade == null);<code>
```

But Entity do this:

```
SELECT 
CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS C1, 
CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS C2, 
CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS C3, 
CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS C4, 
CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS C5, 
CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS C6, 
CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS C7, 
CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS C8, 
CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS C9, 
CAST(NULL AS timestamp) AS C10
FROM  ( SELECT CAST(1 AS int) AS X FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 ) AS SingleRowTable1
WHERE CAST('t' AS boolean) = CAST('f' AS boolean)
```

And Give-me an error:

> exception -> ERROR [42846] [CLASS][DB2/NT64] SQL0461N  A value with
>   data type "SYSCLASS.VARCHAR" cannot be CAST to type
>   "SYSCLASS.BOOLEAN".
>
> and on debug in DB2:
>
> -- Failed in 355 ms with error: ERROR [42846] [CLASS][DB2/NT64] SQL0461N  A value with data type "SYSCLASS.VARCHAR" cannot be CAST to type
>   "SYSCLASS.BOOLEAN".

I have a nullable field on DB2 Table. How Make Is Null Comparison?

On sqlserver works fine...but in db2....

Comment: I don't think it's about NULL -- the framework generates `WHERE CAST('t' AS boolean) = CAST('f' AS boolean)` but DB2 SQL does not support the BOOLEAN data type.

Comment: The framework does not generate queries, is the provider (the SQL dialect is different for every DBMS). The provider knows about supported types...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague at work helped me.
My map was wrong. The field idAtividade is nullable. The relation need be optional.

```
this.HasRequired (T => t.ATIVIDADE)
                 .WithMany (T => t.PERFIL_ALERTAs)
                 .HasForeignKey (T => t.IdAtividade);
```

correction

```
this.HasOptional (T => t.ATIVIDADE)
.WithMany (T => t.PERFIL_ALERTAs)
.HasForeignKey (T => t.IdAtividade);
```